What font(s) support all/most of the Chinese glyphs?
I am rendering unicode characters, with the Noto Sans series of CJK fonts, and they are missing lots of characters (notice the bar-boxes, and the serif styled glyphs, as opposed to the Sans Serif Noto glyphs).

Not even the fallback chain of Noto Sans SC, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif fills in the missing glyphs.
What are some fonts which can cover all (or most) unicode Chinese glyphs? Maybe even several fonts to cover the ones each font is missing, but the fonts are close?

These might have some answers for you: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22How+to+display+CJK+Extension%22

Jigmo (字雲)
It features 141,457 characters included in ISO/IEC 10646 and the Unicode standard. It supports the additions of Unicode 15.1 up to Ext.I, CJK Unified Ideographs Extension I.

So far I haven't seen a font type cover all character. An easy way to check if a font type has large collection or not is its file size. The larger the file, the more likely it has larger collection.
My recommended font: Kai font type from 教育部 of Taiwan:
edukai font
It collected 13084 characters.

This is a very obnoxious problem and good fonts are hard to find and identify. I recommend using BabelMap (Windows, runs under Wine on Linux); you get a window with a grid showing characters for all the Unicode code points. You can select a CJK block (e.g. CJK Unified Ideographs Extension C) and the app will display all characters present in the selected font. Now, crucially, to select the font you can use the "configure" button which opens a dialogue that lists all the fonts offered by the OS together with their code point coverage, which you can sort by number of code points; it also tells you how many code points the respective block has defined so you can easily judge what the fonts with the best coverage are.
While you're on https://www.babelstone.co.uk, you might as well check their fonts section, where they list, among others, BabelStone Han, which has a pretty good overall coverage.

Try https://fonts.google.com/. There are several Chinese and Japanese font packages

Nope, they are all missing many.
